# Jquery and Java(Servlet) File Uploading with delete,Abort,Download ..... options

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, servlets

I am trying to upload file ( using Jquery and Servlet)

1. Landing page
2. Click on Add files button to add Multiple file and calling servlet. 
   File is uploaed successfully. And As a response I am getting json data..

Servlet File :
    **UploadServlet.java**

```
    public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private File fileUploadPath;   
    public void init(ServletConfig config) {
        fileUploadPath = new File(config.getInitParameter("upload_path"));
    }
   @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (request.getParameter("getfile") != null && !request.getParameter("getfile").isEmpty()) {        
           File file = new File(fileUploadPath,request.getParameter("getfile"));            
            if (file.exists()) {
                int bytes = 0;
                ServletOutputStream op = response.getOutputStream();

                response.setContentType("text/html");
                response.setContentType(getMimeType(file));
                response.setContentLength((int) file.length());
                response.setHeader( "Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"" );

                byte[] bbuf = new byte[1024];
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
                while ((in != null) && ((bytes = in.read(bbuf)) != -1)) {
                    op.write(bbuf, 0, bytes);
                }
                in.close();
                op.flush();
                op.close();
            }
        } else if (request.getParameter("delfile") != null && !request.getParameter("delfile").isEmpty()) {
         File file = new File(fileUploadPath, request.getParameter("delfile"));
            if (file.exists()) {
                file.delete(); // TODO:check and report success
            } 
        } else if (request.getParameter("getthumb") != null && !request.getParameter("getthumb").isEmpty()) {
         File file = new File(fileUploadPath, request.getParameter("getthumb"));
         BufferedImage im =null;
                if (file.exists()) {
                    String mimetype = getMimeType(file);
                    if (mimetype.endsWith("png") || mimetype.endsWith("jpeg") || mimetype.endsWith("gif")           

                    {    im = ImageIO.read(file);       
                             if (im != null) {
                            BufferedImage thumb = Scalr.resize(im, 75); 
                            ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            if (mimetype.endsWith("png")) {
                                ImageIO.write(thumb, "PNG" , os);
                                response.setContentType("image/png");
                            } else if (mimetype.endsWith("jpeg")) {
                                ImageIO.write(thumb, "jpg" , os);
                                response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
                            } else if (mimetype.endsWith("gif")) {
                                ImageIO.write(thumb, "GIF" , os);
                                response.setContentType("image/gif");
                            }else{
                                ImageIO.write(thumb, "doc" , os);
                                response.setContentType("image/doc");
                            }
                            ServletOutputStream srvos = response.getOutputStream();
                            response.setContentLength(os.size());
                            response.setHeader( "Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"" );
                            os.writeTo(srvos);
                            srvos.flush();
                            srvos.close();
                        }
                    }
            } 
       } else {
            PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
            writer.write("call POST with multipart form data");
        }
    }    

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        if (!ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Request is not multipart, please 'multipart/form-data' enctype for your form.");
        }
        DiskFileItemFactory ldch_disk_file = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        ldch_disk_file.setRepository(fileUploadPath);         
        ServletFileUpload uploadHandler = new ServletFileUpload(ldch_disk_file);
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
        try {
            List<FileItem> items = uploadHandler.parseRequest(request);
            for (FileItem item : items) {
                if (!item.isFormField()) {
                        File file = new File(fileUploadPath, item.getName());
                        item.write(file);
                        JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject();
                        jsono.put("name", item.getName());
                        jsono.put("size", item.getSize());
                        jsono.put("url", "upload?getfile=" + item.getName());
                        jsono.put("thumbnail_url", "upload?getthumb=" + item.getName());
                        jsono.put("delete_url", "upload?delfile=" + item.getName());
                        jsono.put("delete_type", "GET");
                        json.put(jsono);
                }
            }
        } catch (FileUploadException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            writer.write(json.toString());
            writer.close();
        }
    }
    private String getMimeType(File file) {
        String mimetype = "";
        if (file.exists()) {
            if (getSuffix(file.getName()).equalsIgnoreCase("png")) {
                mimetype = "image/png";
            } else  if (getSuffix(file.getName()).equalsIgnoreCase("docx")) {
                mimetype = "image/doc";
            }else {
                javax.activation.MimetypesFileTypeMap mtMap = new javax.activation.MimetypesFileTypeMap();
                mimetype  = mtMap.getContentType(file);
            }        }
        System.out.println("mimetype: " + mimetype);
        return mimetype;
    }
    private String getSuffix(String filename) {
        String suffix = "";
        int pos = filename.lastIndexOf('.');
        if (pos > 0 && pos < filename.length() - 1) {
            suffix = filename.substring(pos + 1);
        }
        System.out.println("suffix: " + suffix);
        return suffix;  
    }
```

3. But on the page I m not getting proper result.
   (what is the problem here ... Please Help.)

Source Code: 
[Source Code Link](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/jquery-ui.html)